# How should I install a zsh completion function so that it works for all users, regardless of their config?

Tags: zsh

I have written a script for internal use in my job (it's not of much use to anyone outside of my work). I've got a decent `zsh` completion script for it now which works great. I'd like to add an `--install-zsh-completions` flag to my script, which sets up completions automatically.

I see that there are a variety of different ways that `zsh` can be set up, depending on whether you use oh-my-zsh, prezto or your own configuration. (For example, in `oh-my-zsh`, you can put completion scripts in `~/.oh-my-zsh/completions` and they are loaded.)

Is there a *standard place or way in `zsh`* to install custom completion functions, so that they work for all users, regardless of their `zsh` config? (For example, should I just modify the `.zshrc` file and add to the `fpath`? )

Comment: Be sure to print the relevant code snippet so that the users can adapt it to their own config. They might have changed the default `fpath`. Do NOT touch `.zshrc`. It's a very rude thing to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a standard place or way in zsh to install zsh custom completion scripts?

Yes, there is: Create a symlink in `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` that points to your completion function. That's all there is to it.

This dir is by default in every user's `$fpath`. So, when they (or whatever framework they're using) calls `compinit`, it will be picked up automatically.

Comment: @simon I now slightly updated my answer to say you should create a symlink. That way, you don’t have copy your function again whenever you update your software.