# How can I get Bash and Zsh completions for VS Code on the commandline?

Tags: visual-studio-code, bash-completion

I would like to get Bash completions for `code`. How can that be done?

I tried using the search bar to see if this had already been asked ([`is:q [vscode] bash completion`](/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bvscode%5D+bash+completion), [`is:q [vscode] [bash-completion]`](/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bvscode%5D+%5Bbash-completion%5D), [`is:q [vscode] zsh completion`](/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bvscode%5D+zsh+completion), [`is:q [vscode] [zsh-completion]`](/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bvscode%5D+%5Bzsh-completion%5D)) and googling "`how to get bash completions for vscode`" and "`how to get zsh completions for vscode`". I didn't see any existing Q&A on this topic (or maybe I just missed it?). I did find [Add command line completion in zsh for the "code" command #47101](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47101), but that didn't really answer my quesiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code provides Bash and Zsh completion files. The source code templates can be found in [`resources/completions/bash/code`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/resources/completions/bash/code) and [`resources/completions/zsh/_code`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/resources/completions/zsh/_code).

[Looking at the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/search?q=completions%2Fbash), at the time of this writing, this file is only made part of the installation for Linux builds, where the completions files is placed in `usr/share/code/resources/completions/{bash,zsh}/code` (and also other directories).

I'm not sure if you actually have to do anything for Deb or RPM installations or if those are integrated automatically. But I definitely did have to take manual action for my Snap installation.

You can either source this file into one of your shell profile files (wherever they are, such as ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, etc.), or you can copy or symlink it to one of the locations that your shell looks for completion files. For example, for [the Bash completion project](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion), the `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` script looks in a directory defined by `local -a dirs=(${BASH_COMPLETION_USER_DIR:-${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}/bash-completion}/completions)`. See also [Standard place for user defined bash_completion.d scripts?](https://serverfault.com/q/506612/993961)

For my Snap installation, I did `ln -sT /snap/code/current/usr/share/code/resources/completions/bash/code ~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/code`.

Comment: In Ubuntu 23.04, adding `source /usr/share/code/resources/completions/zsh/_code` to the top of my `.zshrc` file does not fix auto-complete with `code` from the command line. From zsh, when I try to run `code <tab to start auto-complete>` I get the error: `_arguments:comparearguments:327: can only be called from completion function`.

Comment: @Jayden.Cameron why do you have an underscore in your `/_code`? The file's path is actually like that?

Comment: Yes, the file path has the leading underscore for zsh. You have it also in your answer to the OP when you wrote "and `resources/completions/zsh/_code`. Renaming the file from `_code` to `code` (with or without sourcing from `.zshrc`) does not fix the problem. The command line still returns error `(eval):1: command not found: _code.dpkg-new`. It seems to be looking for `_code.dpkg-new`, but I'm not sure why or where.

Comment: Also, adding a symlink in `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` to `/usr/share/code/resources/completions/zsh/_code` did not help. Same error: `(eval):1: command not found: _code.dpkg-new`. (Found location for zsh completions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67695861/how-should-i-install-a-zsh-completion-function-so-that-it-works-for-all-users-r#:~:text=6-,Is%20there%20a%20standard%20place%20or%20way%20in%20zsh%20to,default%20in%20every%20user's%20%24fpath%20.))

Comment: I originally installed VS code using `apt` following [this tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-vscode-ubuntu). Uninstalling then reinstalling with `snap` using the same tutorial resolved the issue. Not sure what is wrong with the `apt` installation, but I'm glad the issue is resolved now. Thanks for your posts, @starball.